# lilypond instrumentName breaks geometry

Tags: lilypond

I have a score which looks great, until I try to set the `instrumentName`:

Without `instrumentName`:

[image]

With `instrumentName`:

[image]

```
\score {                                                                        
  \new StaffGroup <<                                                            
    \new Staff \with {                                                          
      instrumentName = "Baß Tube I&II in B"      
    }{                                                                          
      \transpose c bes                                                          
      <<                                                                        
        \new Voice = "TenorIb" { \voiceOne \tenortubaib }                       
        \new Voice = "TenorIIb" { \voiceTwo \tenortubaiib }                     
      >>                                                                        
    }                                                                           
    \new Staff \with {                                                           
      instrumentName = "Baß Tube I&II in F"    
    }{                                                                          
      \transpose c f                                                            
      <<                                                                        
        \new Voice = "basIf" { \voiceTwo \bastubaif }                           
        \new Voice = "basIIf" { \voiceOne \bastubaiif }                         
      >>                                                                        
    }                                                                           
    \new Staff \with {                                                          
      instrumentName = "Kontrabaß Tuba"          
    }{                                                                          
      \clef bass                                                                
      \tuba                                                                     
    }                                                                           
  >>                                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paper block is used to set values such as the indention values.

To make enough room for those (long) instrument names you'll need to set the indentation value to something greater than the default (`15\mm`), say:

```
\paper {
    indent = 35\mm
}
```

If you are also using short instrument names (e.g. `shortInstrumentName = "Btb."`) you can set the short indent value (default `0\mm`) in the paper block too, with say: `short-indent = 10\mm`.

---

You can use units other than `\mm` (millimetres), such `\cm`, `\in`, `\pt`.

Other paper block variables can be found here:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/horizontal-spacing-paper-variables

Comment: This saved me.  After this, I also thought about those "long" names.  `instrumentName = \markup \right-column { "Tenor Tube" "I&II in B" }` let me split the long name onto two lines which helped me reduce the indent to `20\mm`.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is I am integrating `lilypond` into `latex`.  It appears `latex` overrides the default paper indent to `0`, that is wonderful for single-staff excerpts, but caused this problem to be even worse.  Setting paper indent in `lilypond` is a really good solution, even if you are just setting it back to the `15\mm`

Comment: I find something like this looks rather nice: `\markup { \hcenter-in #20 { \center-column { \vspace #+0.2 \line { "Clarinet" } \vspace #-0.3 \tiny \concat { "in B" \flat } } } \hspace #-1.7 \small \center-column { "1" "2" \vspace #-0.3 } }`, but it is a bit fiddly.

Comment: @Stewart I love LaTeX, but I haven't used it in a while.  
When I compile you code, the left side of the page spills, rather than (as in your image) the right.  So I guess LaTeX is overriding more "page variables" than just the indentation.